# Search and replace a pattern in vim only for a fixed number of occurences of pattern

Tags: vim

How do I do search and replace(in vim) for say only the first 4 occurences of the pattern?

Answer (score 5):

The built-in way: Specify the `/c` "confirm" flag to the `:substitute` command, and answer with `y` four times, then abort with `q`. You can also automate that:

```
:call feedkeys('yyyyq') | %s/{pattern}/{string}/gc
```

---

The plugin-way: My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides a `:SubstituteSelected` command:

```
:%SubstituteSelected/{pattern}/{string}/g 1-4
```